# Why does my button function executes onload of my win32 projcet? C++

Tags: windows, user-interface, visual-c++

I've created a basic GUI using the windows library and I've come across a problem. The GUI builds and performs great but the issue is the button functions execute before the actual window loads. I wanted the button to execute the desired function on press rather than on load. Below is the code where I think the problem lies.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("T3chSpl01ts Version - 1.0");

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            
            TextOut(hdc,
                5, 5, 
                greeting, _tcslen(greeting));
        
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            break;

        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            Button = CreateWindow("Button", "Inject",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 20, 20, 100, 30,
                hWnd, (HMENU)ID_INJECT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        }

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case ID_INJECT:
                {
                    ::test();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WM_CREATE` handler is missing a `break` statement, so code flow "falls through" into your `WM_COMMAND` handler when the window is created.